# Spring Boot vs. Groovy Templates - can't iterate over a list inside the ModelAndView

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, groovy

I am evaluating Spring Boot for a future application and wanted to use the Groovy templates for their sheer readable beauty. Unfortunately I am having trouble with iterating over a list of objects I am adding to the ModelAndView object returned from the controller.

This is my controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/ships")
public class ShipsController {

    @Autowired
    ShipDao shipDao;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView ships() {
        final ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("views/ships");
        modelAndView.addObject("ships", this.shipDao.findAll());
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

And this is my template:

```
yieldUnescaped '<!DOCTYPE html>'
html(lang:'en') {
    head {
        meta('http-equiv':'"Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"')
        title('My page')
    }
    body {
        p('Look at all these ships:')
        ul {
            ships.each { ship ->
                li('$ship.name')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But all I get to see in the browser is this:

> Look at all these ships:
>
> $ship.name

I was able to assure myself that the list returned from the DAO contains three entities, yet this appears to be ignored / not recognized by the template.

What also strikes me odd is that even if *ships* isn't present in the template, why does it even show one *li* element? I would have expected none in that case (empty list) or rather an error for referencing a null object.

Anyone with an idea?

**Edit**

I've just tried the same with Thymeleaf templates and it works like a charm. Therefore it's not my controllers.

Could it be that you can use Groovy templates only with Groovy and not with Java?

Comment: Did you intend to use `li("${ship.name}")` instead of `li('$ship.name')`?

Comment: Or even `li(ship.name)`

Comment: Thanks for your comments. This is interesting. If I try Tim's idea, I'll get an NPE saying "Cannot get property 'name' on null object", so therefore ship must be null. If I try Jeff's idea, I'll get one li element with "ships" as text.

Comment: btw, I followed the example on Spring's doc:

https://spring.io/blog/2014/05/28/using-the-innovative-groovy-template-engine-in-spring-boot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem with groovy templates. It appears that groovy template engine wraps your template code into a temporary class named after the template file. In your case it creates class named `ships` and that class name hides your model attribute. So, `ships.each{...}` trys to iterate over an instance of type `Class<ships>`.

You can either rename the model attribute or use spring's implicit RequestContext attribute like `spring.model.ships.each{...}`

Comment: Awesome, you just saved my day - because today is decision day and now it works. Thanks a lot, I wish I could upvote you more than once. :)